# Accessing managed code extensions in a excel workbook

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel-2007

I am writing a program in c# and need to use excel for part of it. I don't feel like using com directly and would prefer to write a *workbook* extension in visual studio, but I am wondering if I can then access that extension from another program and let it do the excel work then send data back. And yes, I am very new to this.

**Edit:** Maybe there is a way to do this without excel, because all I need it for is to parse an html email to get its tables. If I could do this I would probably have it return a 2D array containing the data I need. If anyone has an idea on how to do it without excel, that is welcome too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have microsoft office installed on a machine, then yes, you can access the Excel dlls from within a C# program in visual studio.

Programming this is not easy though.

Comment: just to make it clear, I'm talking about accessing the workbook extension that I also make in visual studio.